# Does air have gravitational mass?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, air, buoyancy, fluid-statics

Air has inertial mass, obviously, but can it be said to have gravitational mass?

Clearly there is a asymmetrical relation between cold air and hot air on the axis going towards and away from the earth (hot air rises), but that does not mean that it has some natural attraction to some other body.

Consider fluid mechanics of smoke emitted from a cigarette.  You see there not particles moving from kinetic energy equations, you see the hot burning "air" *rising* -- that buoyoncy is not a gravitational movement.  That is anti-gravitational movement.

Comment: Yes, without gravity it would all fly off into space as the air molecules moved in a straight line away from the Earth.

Comment: Earth moving or not doesn't matter in this case. Without the pull of gravity acting on the molecules in the air, each molecule would go on its own straight line away from the Earth.

Comment: Plant life takes in air and keeps it close and it's been doing it for a long time, apparently without gravity.

Comment: Umm, where are there plants living without gravity?

Comment: I've clarified my question.  The better example is in fluid mechanics.  There, you see not a gravitational phenemonon, but something relating only to cold and hot air relationships.  If it was kinetic energy, the smoke would be moving away much more randomly.

Comment: You should look into the phenomenon of buoyancy. It applies to air just as much as it applies to water, the water is just 1000X less dense.

Comment: Yes, but again, it is an anti-gravitational phenomenon -- it moves away and is non-attraction.

Comment: If a large kid and a small kid get on a see-saw, and the small kid rises up in the air is that anti-gravity?

Comment: Nope, the rigidity of the wood did the work of lifting the smaller kid.

Comment: No, the wood only served as a conduit for the force. The work was done by the gravitational force pulling the larger child down. Likewise with buoyancy, the work is done by gravity pulling down the denser (because it's colder) air, forcing the hotter air up.

Comment: @SeanLake:  perhaps we should debate in chat, but I think you are trying to save physics.  The wood isn't simply a conduit, it is doing a type of work.  Other, non-rigid matter wouldn't make the smaller kid "buoyant", so if s/he was innately rising from "kinetic energy interactions" it wouldn't make a difference, but where is the "wood plank" in the smoke rising from the cigarette?.

Comment: Why does liquid nitrogen, the primary component of the atmosphere, weigh something? Why does a canister of compressed air weigh more than one with atmospheric pressure air?

Comment: Liquid nitrogen weighs more because it takes less volume per equal parts N.  Compressed air, however, may not "weigh" more.  Have you tried it?  I mean have you verified that it weights more relative to Earth, rather than a vacuum, which may exhibit a buoyancy effect -- the very peculiarity I'm trying to question and discern.

Answer (score 1):

Take two fixed volume rigid containers of the same size and mass. Create a vacuum in one and fill the other with an amount of gas to exert atmospheric pressure (or any non-zero pressure for that matter). Place each on a scale. The one with the air will weigh more. The Earth will pull on it with a greater gravitational force. Likewise, by Newton's Third Law, the box with the air will pull on the Earth with a greater force due to the additional mass of the air within.

Edit (in response to OP's edit)
The rising of hot air isn't due to antigravity, it's due to buoyancy. The more dense cooler air sinks, migrates under the less dense smoke and lifts it.

Comment: No, the air will not press on the plate more.  If anything, the one with the vacuum will simply rise due to the buoyancy effect.  It's that the latter weighs *less*.

Comment: Same experiment can be done on the moon with the same result.

Comment: Why is it buoyant? Because it has less density. It has less density due to less mass per unit volume. Less mass means less gravitational attraction, the driving principle of buoyancy.

Comment: @SeanLake:  Ahh, but can it be done in space?  Will the air inside the box be irrelevant to the mass equation on its gravitational pull since all particles are hitting the box equally in random directions?

Answer (score 1):

All matter is composed of elementary particles bound in various forms, hierarchically into atoms and molecules. The binding is electromagnetic. From that level, the relativistic invariant mass of the agglomerates is the same as the inertial mass and the gravitational mass, and the rule " mass is conserved" used in counting coins by weight , holds to great accuracy. Gravitational mass and inertial mass are the same within the non relativistic everyday velocities.

**All matter has gravitational mass** and is attracted by the collective gravitational field of the earth. Water is less dense ( smaller mass per unit volume) than sand and stays on top. Air is less dense than ground and water, feels less attraction per unit volume, and stays on top .

> Consider fluid mechanics of smoke emitted from a cigarette. You see there not particles moving from kinetic energy equations, you see the hot burning "air" rising -- that buoyoncy is not a gravitational movement. That is anti-gravitational movement.

When one considers a system of matter, in the above case air with smoke/heat one has to take into account all the forces entering the problem. Buoyancy has been studied from the time of [Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle)  and is dependent on the gravitational field where the fluid resides  and the density per unit volume of the fluid. Hot air is less dense than cold air, feels less gravitational force and rises to the level where the gravitational force of attraction for the hot bubble  balances the pressure of the column of air ( pressure is induced by the pull of  gravitation on the mass of air above the hot air bubble).

Gravity induces density stratification.

These are well understood algebraic problems and cannot be dismissed by handwaving and confused arguments.